# rTorrent: Automatically erase data when torrent is removed?

Tags: rtorrent

I want rTorrent to delete a torrent's data when I remove it from the UI.

I've looked through the `.rtorrent.rc` documentation, and found the `on_erase` settings, but it is now depreciated.
The replacement for it, `system.method.set_key = event.download.erased` is not very well documented.

What should I add to my `.rotorrent.rc` in order to make it delete files when I remove a torrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
method.set_key = event.download.erased, remove_file,"execute={rm,-drf,--,$d.get_base_path=}"
```

for rtorrent 0.9.2

Comment: This did work, but after updating to Ubuntu 12.04 I now get "Event 'event.download.erased' failed: Bad return code."

Comment: I use ArchLinux. Maybe the rtorrent version in Ubuntu 12.04 is not v0.9.2?

Comment: I compiled from scratch before the upgrade. rtorrent gui is reporting - rTorrent 0.9.2/0.13.2. Will scout around the issue queue

Comment: it doesn't work anymore on 0.9.4

Answer (score 2):

It works with 0.9.7 and the latest version (0.9.8):

```
method.set_key = event.download.erased,delete_erased,"execute=rm,-rf,--,$d.base_path="
```

You need to add this line in `.rtorrent.rc` file.